# npm does not install when i run npm install -g comand

Tags: node.js, npm

Npm doesn't install. My Node version is v10.14.2 and my npm version is 6.4.1.
This is the error I'm getting:

```
npm install npm -g
npm ERR! code E400
npm ERR! 400 Bad Request: npm@latest

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Dev Akash\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-12-24T10_58_41_162Z-debug.log
```

Comment: What command have you pasted? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Did you check the debug.log file ?

Comment: i want to install vue-cli but when i past npm install -g vue-cli command this error showe up

Comment: TGrif, how i check the debug.log file? Please help

Comment: Just open it with your favorite text editor.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 7 32 bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using wrong 
change `npm install -g npm`
if you want to install any plugin or package then you will use 
`npm install -g PackageName/plugin` 
example: i want to install cordova then i will use

```
npm install -g cordova
```

and install npm then

```
npm install -g npm
```